# How can i get rid of unpredictable speed peaks during speed measurements?

Tags: swift, geolocation, location, core-location

I had wrote service for user speed tracking.This service is using `Core Location` framework to track geo points and do calculation of the user speed.

Service example:

```
private func processLocation(_ current:CLLocation) {
    guard let location = lastLocation else {
        lastLocation = current
        speed.value = 0
        return
    }
    var speed = current.speed
    if (speed > 0) {
        speed.value = speed
    } else {
        speed = location.distance(from: current) / (current.timestamp.timeIntervalSince(location.timestamp))
        speed.value = speed
    }
    lastLocation = current
}
```

This service is working with acceptable accuracy. But there is a case when you are stationary and this service receive quite a lot of unpredictable peaks.

Log when I am stationary.

```
Speed: 0.249200397696353
Speed: 0.778375328912623
Speed: 6.99212664940017 -> peak
Speed: 4.91809055561385 -> peak
Speed: 0.701735999364708
Speed: 0.025146066057472
Speed: 0.0233857682731226
Speed: 12.7814687721084 -> peak
Speed: 0.61632553168542
Speed: 7.37520678279276 -> peak
Speed: 0.023421072500409
Speed: 0.0343784939631481
Speed: 0.471982071125438
Speed: 0.0207671001927932
Speed: 0.0217459598583271
Speed: 0.0394697185852203
Speed: 0.439568634647097
Speed: 14.1348693612176 -> peak
Speed: 6.29588775714151 -> peak
Speed: 5.55254459904619 -> peak 
Speed: 0.218587071425142
```

How can I get rid of unpredictable peaks in this speed tracking service? Should I do better configuration of the `Core Location` manager ?

Comment: are these peaks coming from distance calculation?

Comment: @Scriptable yeah you are right distance/time

Comment: If you want better results, you could try to refine them combining CoreMotion with CoreLocation so that, for example, if you are stationary,  you can filter at certain speed thresholds, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a **Median Filter** for reducing data peaks. Define a threshold for detecting peak values and apply filter on them. Refer to this document https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/median.htm